# Unable to open the log file "../log/backend_dev.log" for writing?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I am new to symfony, I am  reading `Practical Symfony`, I am working on both Linux and Windows. I use GitHub to move my changes. yesterday i created a small project on my windows machine and pushed it to github `https://github.com/showketbhat/medicine`. I pulled the code today on Linux machine i changed some configurations for my database. now when i try to open my index page it shows me the following error message :-

```
500 | Internal Server Error | sfFileException
```

Unable to open the log file "D:\sfproject\medicine\log/backend_dev.log" for writing.
stack trace

```
* at ()
  in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/log/sfFileLogger.class.php line 75 ...
          72.     $fileExists = file_exists($options['file']);
          73.     if (!is_writable($dir) || ($fileExists && !is_writable($options['file'])))
          74.     {
          75.       throw new sfFileException(sprintf('Unable to open the log file "%s" for writing.', $options['file']));
          76.     }
          77.
          78.     $this->fp = fopen($options['file'], 'a');
```

I tried to change the permission to 777 for `backend_dev.log` file, but nothing happen. can anyone help me out?

After Using php symfony project:permissions

```
>> chmod 777 /home/sfprojects/medicine/cache
>> chmod 777 /home/sfprojects/medicine/log
>> chmod 777 /home/sfprojects/medicine/symfony 
....
....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you must clear the cache and reload the page.

```
rm -rf cache/*
```

or

```
php symfony cc
```

Answer (score 0):

The path in the error message, `D:\sfproject\medicine\log/backend_dev.log`, is a Windows path, not a Linux path. I'm guessing you have that set in a config file somewhere -- change it to a valid path on your Linux machine.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is the actual problem, and i dont know how can i change it. I tried to find this string D:\sfproject\medicine\ but couldn't find. So can u help me here

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant which is given by your php installation und is differet between unix and windows.